# Redshift INSERT INTO TABLE from CTE

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, common-table-expression, amazon-redshift

According to the Redshift WITH Clause [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html), you can use a WITH clause with a `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement. However when testing this, I am getting the below error. Is this not possible, or do I have the syntax wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE TestCTEInsert (SomeTimestamp TIMESTAMP);
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT GETDATE() as SomeTimestamp)
INSERT INTO TestCTEInsert
    (SomeTimestamp) SELECT SomeTimestamp from CTE;
```

> ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "insert"

Interestingly, it does support inserting into a new table i.e.

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT GETDATE() as SomeTimestamp)
INSERT SomeTimestamp INTO NewTable 
SELECT SomeTimestamp from CTE;
```

> The command completed successfully (1 rows affected)

**EDIT:** Just to confirm, I get the same error when using an `INTEGER` column rather than `TIMESTAMP`:

```
CREATE TABLE TestCTE (SomeInt INTEGER);
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT 1 as SomeInt)
INSERT INTO TestCTEInsert 
SELECT SomeInt from CTE;
```

> ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "insert"

Comment: try removing  (SomeTimestamp)  in the insert

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This returns the same error: `ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "insert"`

Comment: As far as i know, you cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column.

Comment: Thanks @AksheyBhat but I don't think this is the problem here. I recreated this with an integer column rather than timestamp and got the same error message.

Comment: The `;` goes at the **end** of a statement not somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try putting the CTE in the insert (not sure if that beats the point)

```
INSERT INTO TestCTEInsert
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as SomeTimestamp)
SELECT SomeTimestamp from CTE;
```

Answer (score 7):

The `;` **terminates** a statement, so it needs to go at the end of the statement, not somewhere in the middle:

You can do this in two ways, either use a `create table as select`

```
create table TestCTEInsert 
as
WITH CTE AS
(  
   SELECT current_timestamp as SomeTimestamp
)
SELECT SomeTimestamp 
from CTE; -- ; only at the end
```

Or in two steps:

```
CREATE TABLE TestCTEInsert (SomeTimestamp TIMESTAMP); -- end this with a ;

insert into TestCTEInsert
WITH CTE AS
(  
   SELECT current_timestamp as SomeTimestamp
)
SELECT SomeTimestamp 
from CTE; -- ; only at the end
```

The above runs on a vanilla Postgres installation, I don't have access to RDS

Comment: Thanks for your help @a_horse_with_no_name. The semicolon in my script was just to separate the CREATE TABLE and the CTE insert so I could do this in two steps (like your second query above). I have accepted Adeeb's answer as he was a little quicker with his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Change your script to this

```
  CREATE TABLE TestCTE (SomeInt INTEGER)
  WITH CTE AS (SELECT 1 as SomeInt) 
  INSERT INTO TestCTE  SELECT SomeInt from CTE;
```

Comment: This returns the same error. `ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "insert"`. I recreated this with an integer column rather than timestamp and got the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 CREATE TABLE TestCTE (SomeInt INTEGER)
;WITH CTE AS
(SELECT 1 as SomeInt)
INSERT (SomeInt) INTO TestCTE
SELECT SomeInt FROM CTE;
```